# How do i share my script so others can use it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I did make a script using Apps script. the script takes information out of my google sheet (when i click a button in my sheet), and makes a pdf of it using a template file.

- for me the script is working fine, but whaen i share my **file** to a college in the same orginisation with writing promission they can not use the buttonto create pdf's.

if i look on internet for information i can only find people who share there scripts in apps script itself, but i do not heve that option. **Can you help?**

[not able to share in apps script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb8Dh.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow - https://stackoverflow.com/tour
From your question, it looks like you have a container bound apps script within Google sheets and a function in it to show menu in Sheets. Is that right?
Are you saying that your colleague is not able to see the menu for that button in Sheets? Please describe the issue in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a function with DriveApp/SpreadsheetApp for the first time, it asks for permissions (you login with your google account). It's likely that they your colleague hasn't authorized the script to make any changes on their behalf. They may also need Editor permission for the files and folders you're using.

Based on my knowledge (just checked the Google Apps Script project I have open in another tab), it seems like you can't add collaborators in a project if you're not the owner of the Sheet it's bound to. But your colleague should be able to access the script if they click on Extensions > Apps Script in the Sheet. Then when they run the function in the script editor (instead of clicking button on sheet), they should see the popup asking for authorization.

Let me know if this helps. Happy to help brainstorm if not.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the info.
I did resolve the problem.

- all users of the script need full acces to used links. (if not, they do not have the option to use there extentions)
- all users need to accept the code to work in there account. (what i did for each person seperate (so nothing would go wrong in the script))

thanks again!